# Need help in understanding the below Requirement?

Tags: manual-testing, requirements-validation, boundary-value-analysis, equivalence-partition

Identify minimum number of users to test requirement?

Below you will find the requirements to identify the Account Diversity Grade of a user. Read the requirements carefully and identify what test users you need to setup in order to completely test and make sure all the below requirements are covered. (Note: you should identify the 
optimum (minimum) number of users needed to test all of the requirements)

Requirements: 
A user can have different types of loan accounts.Now we grade a user’s account Diversity based on two factors. 
1) loanTypeCount 
2) totalAccounts

loanTypeCount = the number of different (distinct) LoanType values for all accounts that the 
user has.

However do not include LoanType = Unknown & Collections but include all others 
Applicable values for LoanType are ( Home Loan, Heloc, Credit Card, Car Loan, Collections, 
Unknown)

totalAccounts = total number of loan accounts user has (do not include LoanType = Unknown & 
Collections but include all others)

example-> if user has 3 credit cards and 2 home loans and 1 Collection account, then 
totalAccounts = 5 and loanTypeCount = 2)

The logic to determine accountDiversityGrade is the following:

If totalAccounts> 20 or loanTypeCount >= 4, accountDiversityGrade = A

Else if totalAccounts> 10 or loanTypeCount = 3, accountDiversityGrade = B

Else if totalAccounts>= 5 or loanTypeCount= 2, accountDiversityGrade = C

Else if totalAccounts > 0 or loanTypeCount = 1, accountDiversityGrade = D

Else accountDiversityGrade=null (n/a)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks loke an assignment.

Comment: Agree with dzieciou, this looks like an assignment or interview question.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, 1 user with different/multiple loanAccountTypes.

Now, all snarkyness aside, you should not expect this to be a forum to get your work done by other people. We can help with it, give pointers, feedback to something you have done, but not do it for you completely.

Consider this an exercise, come back with your own solution and we can give a constructive feedback on it.

Comment: Hi , I agree with you answer that given sum require only 1 user. But I am confuse about which method we should apply to count or find minimum users for that? BVA OR EPS?

Comment: Wrong answer, there will larger permutation combination which is equal to number of users.

Comment: Can you please explain how is it possible with the single user? & what about totalAccount?

Comment: User initially has no accounts. Add an account. Add a second account of the same type. Add a third account of a different type. And so on. Easy.